# APPLICATION CRASHING IF WE KEEP IT IN BACKGROUND FOR MORE THAN 15-20 MINS

Tags: android, background

I have devoleped an application and the problem with that application is that Its crashing when we keep it in background for more than 15 mins

On clicking application Icon It should come to foreground but its showing application stopped/ANR message.

So what exactly I have to do so that It will not crash

I think I should concentrate on life cycle methodologies.

Please suggest me a solution for this

Help is always appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of an application are you developing.. Is it calling anything on its background..

Comment: It's hard to say somthing before reading the logcat or the codes.

Comment: @Basil , yes its retrieving the latestdata from cache

Comment: see in your logcat and provide us data which is getting display in lagcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs might not help, when it's an ANR error you are getting. Try instead to pause the application execution (Go to the debug tab, click then pause button and start inspecting the threads) and see what's going on. Most likely you have an infinite loop or deadlock somewhere that is keeping your application from responding.

Answer (score 1):

If on clicking the icon it is showing Application Not Responding Dialogs then there is some variable or data is changing in 15-20 min running time of ur application and that variable or data is being accessed or processed on clicking of your icon and this is giving exception. You can provide your logs so that we can provide you more help